# Cannot resolve method Observable.from in rxjava 2

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

There is a from method in the Observable class in rxjava 1 but not found in rxjava 2. How can I replace the from method in rxjava 2 in the following code:

```
    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
        ints.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    Observable.just(ints)
            .flatMap(new Function<List<Integer>, Observable<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Integer> apply(List<Integer> ints) {
                    return Observable.from(ints);
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `Observable.fromIterable(source)`

From [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0):

> Some operator overloads have been renamed with a postfix, such as
>   fromArray, fromIterable etc. The reason for this is that when the
>   library is compiled with Java 8, the javac often can't disambiguate
>   between functional interface types.

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
    ints.add(new Integer(i));
}
Observable.just(ints)
        .flatMap(new Function<List<Integer>, Observable<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Integer> apply(List<Integer> ints) {
                return Observable.fromIterable(ints);
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to use `.just()` because you can create `Observable` directly from your list via `fromIterable()` operator.

```
    Observable.fromIterable(ints)
```

Answer (score 6):

I guess it's a bit late, but I just wanted to let people know, the API changes related to the `from` operator in the [RxJava documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0):

`from` disambiguated into `fromArray`, `fromIterable`, `fromFuture`

Answer (score 0):

If you need a List then you can simply use Java `Stream` and create a `List` from it and then pass it directly to the [`Observable.fromIterable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#fromIterable-java.lang.Iterable-) method. Like this:

```
Observable.fromIterable(IntStream.rangeClosed(lowerLimitInclusive,upperLimitInclusive)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Or

```
Observable.fromIterable(Stream.iterate(lowerLimitInclusive, integer -> integer + 1)
                .filter(integer -> integer < (upperLimit+1))
                .limit((long(upperLimit+1)-long(lowerLimitInclusive))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```