# How to create Observable<Integer> from infinite Stream<Integer> using RxJava2?

Tags: java, java-stream, rx-java, rx-java2, reactive-streams

I am trying to upgrade RxJava from 1 to 2. In my old code I have a method like below:

```java
private Observable<Integer> reversRange(int from, int to) {
    Stream<Integer> intStream = Stream.iterate(to, p -> p - 1);
    return Observable.from(() -> intStream.iterator())
            .takeWhile(n -> n > from)
            .map(n -> n );
}
```

But now in RxJava 2 I can not use `from`. What would be equivalent of this code?
I have found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605586/cannot-resolve-method-observable-from-in-rxjava-2) that it is `fromIterable` but I do not know how to use it with Stream.

Or other example, this should not be only for range but for any infinite stream.

```java
private Observable<Integer> numbers() {
    Stream<Integer> intStream = Stream.iterate(0, p -> p + 1);
    return Observable.from(() -> intStream.iterator());
}
```

Comment: Do you require a stream of `Integer` only?

Comment: `Integer` is only example. The more generic the better. It shouldn't be only for range.  @ShankhadeepGhoshal

Comment: So you basically need to generate some kind of `Stream<SomeCustomType>` and then create an `Observable` from it?

Comment: Yes, but ideally for infinite stream

Comment: There is a library for working with Java 8 types in RxJava: https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaJdk8Interop#stream-to-rxjava

Comment: @akarnokd is it portable with RxJava2? I'm seeing "RxJava 3 interop library for supporting Java 8 features such as Optional, Stream and CompletableFuture" and in Maven Central the versioning is like 3.x.x. So?....

Comment: The library linked to by akarnokd says it supports both RxJava 2 and 3. However, for RxJava 2 I think you'll have to use an older version (e.g. [version 0.3.7](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaJdk8Interop/releases/tag/v0.3.7)). Any reason why you're migrating to RxJava 2 instead of RxJava 3? Because RxJava 2 [will reach end-of-life at the end of next year](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#version-2x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `generate()` function:

this is kotlin code (an extension function), but you just need to change the lambda slightly. And this works with any stream.

```
fun <T> Stream<T>.toFlowable(): Flowable<T> {
  return Flowable.generate(
    Callable { iterator() },
    BiConsumer { ite, emitter ->
      if (ite.hasNext()) {
        emitter.onNext(ite.next())
      } else {
        emitter.onComplete()
      }
    }
  )
}
```

you can also use `Observable` if you prefer, but I don't see why you should.

```
fun <T> Stream<T>.toObservable(): Observable<T> {
  return Observable.generate(
    Callable { iterator() },
    BiConsumer { ite, emitter ->
      if (ite.hasNext()) {
        emitter.onNext(ite.next())
      } else {
        emitter.onComplete()
      }
    }
  )
}
```

I think in java will be something like:

```
public <T> Observable<T> streamToObservable(Stream<T> stream) {
  return Observable.generate(
    () -> stream.iterator(),
    (ite, emitter) -> {
      if (ite.hasNext()) {
        emitter.onNext(ite.next());
      } else {
        emitter.onComplete();
      }
    }
  );
}
```

and so your code would become:

```
private Observable<Integer> numbers() {
    Stream<Integer> intStream = Stream.iterate(0, p -> p + 1);
    return streamToObservable(intStream);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `Stream` of `Integer` only then you can simply do:

```
Observable.fromIterable(IntStream.rangeClosed(from,to)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Arguments for [`rangedClosed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) are inclusive.

There is another general method that you can use which is closer to what you have in your attempt:

```
Observable.fromIterable(Stream.iterate(from, integer -> integer + 1)
                .filter(integer -> integer < (to+1))
                .limit((long(to+1)-long(from))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

**EDIT1**

If you want an infinite stream. Java Stream's `generate` and `iterate` both produce infinite streams. In my example using `iterate` (you can replace it using `generate` with a `Supplier` where you have your custom object creation code) and get rid of all the terminal operators like `limit`.
Then wrap them into an `Observable` or into a `Flowable` and then into an `Observable` if you want backpressure support with RxJava2.

Like this:

```
Observable.just(Stream.generate(() -> // Object creation logic here));
```

Or

```
Observable.just(Flowable.just(Stream.generate(() -> // Object creation logic here)));
```

Keep in mind that if you do this then your code will keep creating objects indefinitely and your program will run until your memory runs out.
I guess you have some kind of service that is sending you data and you need to make some transformation and send that data as a stream somewhere else. I would recommend getting the data as a `Future` and then wrapping it into a `Flowable` and then streaming the data to wherever you are sending it.
Like:

```
Flowable.fromFuture(senderService.getDataAsCompletableFuture);
```

And then specify a backpressure strategy.

**EDIT2**
You can use `Observable.generate()` to do it.
Like:

```
Observable.generate(() -> from, (value, emitter) -> {
        emitter.onNext(value);
        return value + 1; 
    });
```

Comment: Ultimately, it's creating from a list, I looking for something with infinite stream

Comment: So how can I replace for example this code: `Stream<Integer> intStream = Stream.iterate(0, p -> p + 1); return Observable.from(() -> intStream.iterator());` with `Observable.just` ?

Comment: @lczapski `Observalbe.generate` will be a better idea to go with than `Observable.just`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How to create Observable from infinite Stream using **RxJava2**?

**Like this:**

```java
    public static <T> Observable<T> streamToObservable(Stream<T> stream) {
        return Observable.fromIterable(stream::iterator);
    }
```

**Usage:**

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Some infinite stream
        Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.iterate(1, (i)->i+1);

        //create an observable from the stream
        Observable<Integer> obs = streamToObservable(stream);
        
        //subscribe to the observable
        obs.subscribe((v) -> {
            System.out.println("Value from observable:"+v);
        });
        
    }
```

**output:**

> Value from observable 1
> Value from observable 2
> Value from observable 3
> Value from observable 4
> .........

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130475/1555615) explains how a `Stream` can be converted to `Iterable`.

---

**RxJava3**

```java
//Some infinite stream
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.iterate(1, (i)->i+1);

Observable<Integer> obs = Observable.fromStream(stream);
```